# Completely remove old version of elasticsearch and install newer version

Tags: elasticsearch

There're a lot of articles on the internet regarding new installation of elasticsearch. But I already have 1.x version of elasticsearch running. I want to remove this first and install a newer version. How do I do this? I had used something like this to install the old one:

```
sudo -s  // use as admin

#public key
wget -O - http://packages.elasticsearch.org/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -

# edit /etc/apt/sources.list and add
deb http://packages.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/1.0/debian stable main
deb http://packages.elasticsearch.org/logstash/1.3/debian stable main

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply extract the gzip version of elasticsearch and extract its contents. That's the recommended way. This way you can also keep different versions if you need.

Comment: Yes but i already have a version of ES running, how do I remove it cleanly first? Then I can install newer ones with gzip.

Comment: You can try `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove packagename`

Although if you install newer with gzip, you can simply traverse to that directory and start elasticsearch from there. To make it globall accessible, you can update the PATH variable accordingly